# Copy y-components of a vector

Tags: c++, glm-math

I want to copy the y-components of a vector of the type: `std::vector <glm::vec3> example` because I can't access only the y-components of this vector by doing something like `example.size().y...`. So, I assume I have to copy the content of the y-components to another another vector/array, but is there a way to do that? I was thinking of something like:

```
std::vector <int> something;

    for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)
    {
        something[i] = example[i].y;
    }
```

but it doesn't work apparently.

Thanks!

Comment: In this particular example the problem is that something is empty, therefore you cannot access something[i]. Is that the problem? Did you simply forget to give an initial size to something?

Comment: "Doesn't work apparently", meaning what? Compilation error? Runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the size of the vector grows along with the elements you push into them. The `[]` operator is only an accessor.

```
std::vector <int> something;
something.resize(example.size());

for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)
{
    something[i] = example[i].y;
}
```

Comment: Aha... Well, my C++ is a bit sucky I guess. Thanks for the help, mate! :)

Comment: @Riggs, for the winner of the code-density award , [see here](http://pastebin.com/mUaketTh). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector <int> something;

for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)
{
    something[i] = example[i].y;
}
```

Two issues:

1. `glm::vec3` is a floating-point type, and `example[i].y` is going to return a floating point value. And if these are normalized model vertices, they're very likely all in the range `[-1,1]`, which means that `something[i]` would always be assigned `-1`, `0`, or `1`.
2. `something` never has its memory initialized in the code snippet you're providing. That will cause runtime crashes. You should be writing something like

`std::vector<float> something(example.size());`